# Are There Any CollectionViewSource Alternative with Generic?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, generics, collections

For my WPF application, I need CollectionViewSource to enable selection, filtering, sorting, and grouping in a collection. But CollectionViewSource is not a type safe collection like IList, the property View.CurrentItem is an object for example. We need to cast the items if we use them.

Are there any CollectionViewSource alternatives that support Generic?
Or maybe anybody know the reason why CollectionViewSource is not a generic?

=============================

I made a generic CollectionViewSource based on standard CollectionViewSource.
Any comment whether it is a better alternative for collection class that is instantiated outside XAML? Or there is another better alternative?

Edit 1: Add Generic CollectionViewSource

```
namespace Data
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    public class CollectionViewSource<T> : CollectionViewSource
    {
        public T CurrentItem => this.View != null ? (T)this.View.CurrentItem : default(T);

        public new IEnumerable<T> Source
        {
            get
            {
                return (IEnumerable<T>)base.Source;
            }

            set
            {
                base.Source = value;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> ViewItems => this.View != null ? Enumerable.Cast<T>(this.View) : (IEnumerable<T>)null;

        public CollectionViewSource(IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            this.Source = source;
        }

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            return this.View != null && this.View.Contains(item);
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Groups()
        {
            return this.View.Groups.Cast<T>();
        }

        public void MoveCurrentTo(T item)
        {
            this.View?.MoveCurrentTo(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might not be generic because it is typically instantiated in XAML, and the use of generics in XAML is complicated.

Comment: @Clemens actually I instantiate CollectionViewSource in ViewModel and use as data exchange between ViewModels and Views.

Comment: Sure, but you asked for "the reason why CollectionViewSource is not a generic". Otherwise your question is off-topic, because it asks for a software library, or other off-site resource.

Comment: Yes I understand your points. Thanks.

Comment: There are no generic alternatives in the standard .net Framework that I know of. I had a similar requirement and built a generic `ViewModelCollection` that contains a `ListCollectionView`. The former is used from C# in the ViewModels as read/write and the latter is used from XAML as read-only. It works perfect for our big WPF LOB application but it took months to get it 100% right. We also tried to implement `ICollectionView` and `ICollectionViewLiveShaping` to build a custom `CollectionView` but that's a dead end in my opinion because it never worked due to the lack of official documentation.

Comment: I have added a generic CollectionViewSource in the question. Please comment whether it is a good solution or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually just bind to your `ObservableCollection` (or any collection) and then call `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` for that collection instance, then apply a filter, and your DataGrid (or other items controls) will get filtered. This way you can have your cake and eat it too :-)

The reason for this, I suspect, is because WPF list controls never actually bind to normal .NET collections, but always call `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` behind the scenes, and that seems to return the same instance as the one you already created, if you created one.

Codebehind:

```
MySourceCollection = new[]
{
    new ViewModel(1, "first"),
    new ViewModel(2, "second"),
    new ViewModel(3, "third"),
    new ViewModel(4, "fourth")
};

MyListView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MySourceCollection);
MyListView.Filter = o => ((ViewModel)o).Number >= 3;
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MySourceCollection}" />
```

Result:

[image: Research #QAnon]

I don't know whether this is recommended, but I don't see any problem yet. Just remember that if you reinitialize your source list, you have to call `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` again and reapply your filters.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why its not generic is that the type safety should be in your underlying collection not your view.

The CollectionViewSource is purely for formatting the display of the data, so like a combo and list controls are not typed neither is CollectionViewSource and for exactly the same reason, because they need to work with anything that is given to them

as an example you have a Students Collection, you want to display this in a combo but your also want to be able to select "NEW STUDENT" new student isn't a student so can't be added to the student collection but is a perfectly valid combo item so while the underlying collection has to be Type safe, enforcing the same on the combo is limiting and not protective, out side of your view your code really shouldn't care if values are sorted or not that's usually just a human thing

as for your generic CollectionViewSource, it depends how your are using it if its a good idea not however the type safety should be superflous because your underlying collection should already be doing this.

I would suggest having an `ObservableCollection<T>` as the source of your CollectionViewSource and then just forgetting about Type safing the display